# Navigate through default action in Backbone

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, router

I want to invoke my `defaultAction` function in my `Backbone.Router` but was wondering if there's some standard way of doing this (other than navigating to an undefined route).

So far my best idea is `Backbone.history.navigate("")`. Are there any more robust ones?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`trigger`](http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html#section-179) argument to invoke your route's function

```
router.navigate('', { trigger: true });
```